# Spree Rails multi store subdomains does not work on live server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, subdomain, spree

**I am using** [spree-multi-domain](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree-multi-domain)

*store1.localhost:3000* is working fine locally 
but when I moved my code on the live server I am unable to make it working.
When I hit URL *store1.mydomain.com* it is giving me an error.

```
ERROR:
    This site can’t be reached
    abc.mydomain.com’s server IP address could not be found.
    DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

Also I have tried adding this

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 2
```

in config/enviroments/production.rb

I am on apache server . Do I need to do anything on server side as well to make it working ?

Apache Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias mydomain.com rails        
#        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Comment: Can you share your apache config file here? I hope you have added `ServerName store1.mydomain.com`.

Comment: I have added the file could you please check ? https://files.fm/u/jvsur5mx

Comment: Please add servername and document root path to your rails app public directory `ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.mydomain.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server name missing from your apache config for subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName store1.mydomain.com
  # Tell your app's 'public' directory path
  DocumentRoot /var/www/store1.mydomain.com/public
</VirtualHost>
```

For dynamic or `n` subdomains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
  # Tell your app's 'public' directory path
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you sure I need to add my domains here in this file ? Because in localhost when I add a new Store and add URL i.e demoStore.mydomain.com it just works and also I only see records of that particular Store .Are you familiar with Rails Spree Open source ?

Comment: Also what you have suggested is an alternative because what if admin will create x no of stores how will i change this on server ? I think there would be a better option to do it . Thanks

Comment: I have worked on 0.10.0 spree long back. But here I am feeling much of apache configuration issue. Are you using apache in your local too? Please check updated answer for dynamic subdomains.

Comment: I have understood what you have suggested ,but here in our server where I have installed Rails apache has NO ROLE ,I mean it is running on port :3000 and even if I close apache it does not effect my application . It works normally without apache as well .
Any alternative you can suggest as I am at the end of the development and locally everything is working just fine.